# Mootools. New element with events in loop

Tags: events, mootools, element

I can't find the problem. May be you can help me:

```
load_images: function(config, container, page) {

   console.log(page) // Every time page = 4 Why?
   var paging = new Element('div','class':'pg'}).inject(container,'after'),     
       css_class = '';

   if (data.pages>1) {
     for (var i=1; i<=data.pages; i++) {                        
        css_class   = (i == page) ? 'current' : '';

        new Element('a', {'class':css_class,'href':'javascript:void(0);','html': i,
           events: { 
               click: function(e){
                  load_images(config, container, parseInt(i));
              }
           }
        }).inject(paging);
     }
   }
}

The code above generate HTML:

<div class="pg">
   <a class="current" href="javascript:void(0);">1</a>
   <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">2</a>
   <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">3</a>
</div>
```

When I click to the page link my page variable is 4 (see console.log()). Why?
Thanks.

Comment: what do you want it to be?

Comment: When I click to link 1 - > page should be 1;

Comment: W
hen I click to link 2 - > page should be 2;

Comment: When I click to link 3 - > page should be 3;

Comment: yeah i got it, you dont need to make them separate comments

Comment: So how can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic case of [Javascript Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

The problem is in your case the click event creates closure and close over the i var in the loop so in the end it equals to the last value of i:
what you can do to solve it is something like this in the "for" loop:

```
for (var i=1; i<=data.pages; i++) {                        
        css_class   = (i == page) ? 'current' : '';

        (function(i){
          new Element('a', {'class':css_class,'href':'javascript:void(0);','html': i,
            events: { 
               click: function(e){
                  load_images(config, container, parseInt(i));
              }
           }
         }).inject(paging);
       })(i);
     }
```

this way you are making a copy of i and send it to the anonymous function and it always "keeps" its value.

To understand it completely - read the link I sent - this subject is a bit complected in javascript